# Comprehensive angularFireAuth with email and password example?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I'm trying let my users login with the email and password option provided by Firebase, but I have no idea how it works.

I would really appreciate a comprehensive example, from the html form to pulling up user data after the login attempt is authenticated.

My user data is stored in a table that looks something like this, where the number corresponds to the userid generated by Firebase:

> users
>   -1
>   --name
>   --etc
>   -2
>   --name
>   --etc

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples you can look at for angularFireAuth:

1. angularFire-Seed: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed
2. Firetube: http://firetube.site44.com/ (just look at the source, it's pretty simple)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late for the OP, but to anyone googling, take a look at this [tutorial](https://javebratt.com/angularfire2-authentication-ionic/), it's pretty good.